# Accompanist Pager `offscreenLimit` removed. How to disable preloading of nearby pages?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

Since version v0.19.0; `offscreenLimit` parameter has been [removed](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#horizontalpager-verticalpager). How to disable preloading using some other technique?

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun MyComposable(){
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            count = itemList.size,
        ) { i ->

            MyPage(i)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
HorizontalPager(...) { i ->
    if ((pagerState.currentPage - i).absoluteValue > 1) {
        EmptyPage()
    } else {
        MyPage(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've done something similar; but I thought there could be a cleaner way to achieve this. Guess we have to use this solution for now :)